# Show N rows per page in HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I have an html table with a lot of rows and I use a JavaScript code to add a pagination option, works fine but when I load the document shows all the rows and I want to show only 5, 10, or whatever but not all the rows. Here is my JavaScript code and the working Fiddle:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    getPagination('#Tabla');
});

function getPagination(table) {

  $('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
    $('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination 
    var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter 
    var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option
    var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows 
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter 
      if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows

        $(this).hide(); // fade it out 
      }
      if (trnum <= maxRows) {
        $(this).show();
      } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
    }); //  was fade out to fade it in 
    if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
      var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..  
      //    numbers of pages 
      for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li 
        $('.pagination').append('<li class"wp" data-page="' + i + '">\
                                      <span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
                                    </li>').show();
      } // end for i 
    } // end if row count > max rows
    $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li 
    $('.pagination li').on('click', function() { // on click each page
      var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
      var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
      $('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li 
      $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked 
      $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
        trIndex++; // tr index counter 
        // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
        if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        } //else fade in 
      }); // end of for each tr in table
    }); // end of on click pagination list


    });
}
```

Fiddle:

[Working Code](https://jsfiddle.net/u2e1qvyb/3/)

Comment: Why don't you use a library like https://datatables.net/ for this kind of stuff? You'll get all the nice table features, like sorting, filtering, paging, ...

Comment: Because the table is created dinamycally and I only have access to the front-end.

Comment: Those libraries offer support for that. Quoted from the above link: *"...Supports almost any data source: DOM, JavaScript, ...*".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have changed your code, Check this . The function which is creating the pagination works as it is. Just a minor changes ni code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
            getPagination('#Tabla',$(this).val());
        });
    getPagination('#Tabla',2); // the no of rows default you want to show
});

function getPagination(table,noRows) {

 $('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination 
    var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter 
    var maxRows = noRows; // get Max Rows from select option
    var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows 
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter 
      if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows

        $(this).hide(); // fade it out 
      }
      if (trnum <= maxRows) {
        $(this).show();
      } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
    }); //  was fade out to fade it in 
    if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
      var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..  
      //    numbers of pages 
      for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li 
        $('.pagination').append('<li class"wp" data-page="' + i + '">\
                                      <span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
                                    </li>').show();
      } // end for i 
    } // end if row count > max rows
    $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li 
    $('.pagination li').on('click', function() { // on click each page
      var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
      var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
      $('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li 
      $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked 
      $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
        trIndex++; // tr index counter 
        // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
        if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        } //else fade in 
      }); // end of for each tr in table
    }); // end of on click pagination list
}
```

[Update your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2e1qvyb/5/)

Answer (score 2):

You may select one of the "maxRows" options on document ready. For instance, you may select the last option:

```
$('#maxRows option:last').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
```

You need to trigger the change event so that all is rearranged according to the "change" event.

The snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  getPagination('#Tabla');
  $('#maxRows option:last').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
});

function getPagination(table) {

  $('#maxRows').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination
    var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter
    var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option
    var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter
      if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows

        $(this).hide(); // fade it out
      }
      if (trnum <= maxRows) {
        $(this).show();
      } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
    }); //  was fade out to fade it in
    if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
      var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..
      // numbers of pages
      for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li
        $('.pagination').append('<li class"wp" data-page="' + i + '">\
<span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
</li>').show();
      } // end for i
    } // end if row count > max rows
    $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li
    $('.pagination li').on('click', function() { // on click each page
      var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
      var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
      $('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li
      $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked
      $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
        trIndex++; // tr index counter
        // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
        if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        } //else fade in
      }); // end of for each tr in table
    }); // end of on click pagination list


  });

  // end of on select change



  // END OF PAGINATION
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input col-md-1 col-xs-2">
            <!--  Show Numbers Of Rows   -->
            <select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
                <option value="5000">Show ALL Rows</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="Tabla">
                <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <td>ID<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Family<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="TablaFamilias">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot></tfoot>
            </table>
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works perfect! But Nalin answer was first. Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi gaetanoM, I'm using your modification and works, thank you. The problem is, if you click "full page" link on the right bottom of the html code, the page number selector is shown side by side with the page. How can I modify this behavior showing a small icon, on the top or in the bottom of the page?

Comment: @user1265067 Please, take a look to [](http://getbootstrap.com/css/): container-fluid, row, col- classes and how to build a grid system. Snippet updated. Let me know.

Answer (score 2):

First, I would suggest to use a library for table features like sorting, filtering, paging... as you are really re-inventing the wheel.

But, for the problem you raise, you have to make two adjustments:

1. In your HTML, mark the option with `selected` that has your desired number of pages to display at page load, like 3:

   ```
   <select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
     <option value="5000">Show ALL Rows</option>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
     <option value="3" selected>3</option>
   </select>
   ```
2. In your code, call the `.trigger('change')` method on the `maxRows` element:

   ```
   $('#maxRows').on('change', function() {
       // all code here can stay as it is
       // ...
   }).trigger('change');
   ```

That's it.

See [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2e1qvyb/4/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  getPagination('#Tabla');
  $('#maxRows option:last').prop('selected', true).trigger('change');
});

function getPagination(table) {

  $('#maxRows').on('change', function(e) {
    $('.pagination').html(''); // reset pagination
    var trnum = 0; // reset tr counter
    var maxRows = parseInt($(this).val()); // get Max Rows from select option
    var totalRows = $(table + ' tbody tr').length; // numbers of rows
    $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each TR in  table and not the header
      trnum++; // Start Counter
      if (trnum > maxRows) { // if tr number gt maxRows

        $(this).hide(); // fade it out
      }
      if (trnum <= maxRows) {
        $(this).show();
      } // else fade in Important in case if it ..
    }); //  was fade out to fade it in
    if (totalRows > maxRows) { // if tr total rows gt max rows option
      var pagenum = Math.ceil(totalRows / maxRows); // ceil total(rows/maxrows) to get ..
      //    numbers of pages
      for (var i = 1; i <= pagenum;) { // for each page append pagination li
        $('.pagination').append('<li class"wp" data-page="' + i + '">\
<span>' + i++ + '<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span>\
</li>').show();
      } // end for i
    } // end if row count > max rows
    $('.pagination li:first-child').addClass('active'); // add active class to the first li
    $('.pagination li').on('click', function() { // on click each page
      var pageNum = $(this).attr('data-page'); // get it's number
      var trIndex = 0; // reset tr counter
      $('.pagination li').removeClass('active'); // remove active class from all li
      $(this).addClass('active'); // add active class to the clicked
      $(table + ' tr:gt(0)').each(function() { // each tr in table not the header
        trIndex++; // tr index counter
        // if tr index gt maxRows*pageNum or lt maxRows*pageNum-maxRows fade if out
        if (trIndex > (maxRows * pageNum) || trIndex <= ((maxRows * pageNum) - maxRows)) {
          $(this).hide();
        } else {
          $(this).show();
        } //else fade in
      }); // end of for each tr in table
    }); // end of on click pagination list


  });

  // end of on select change



  // END OF PAGINATION
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="input col-md-1 col-xs-2">
            <!--        Show Numbers Of Rows        -->
            <select class="form-control" name="state" id="maxRows">
                <option value="5000">Show ALL Rows</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row col-md-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="Tabla">
                <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <td>ID<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                    <td>Family<span class="hidden-xs"></span></td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="TablaFamilias">
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>B</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td>D</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td>A</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                <tfoot></tfoot>
            </table>
            <div>
                <nav>
                    <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.