# Table pagination + table styles - how to get rounded edges on the last displayed row

Tags: jquery, css, pagination, css-tables

I've got a table displaying on my site which is paginated. 
I referenced the first answer on this question: [Show N rows per page in HTML table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087619/show-n-rows-per-page-in-html-table/39088125) to figure out how to do the pagination.

The problem is that my table is styled like so:

```
table tr:first-child th:first-child {
    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
}

table tr:first-child th:last-child {
    border-top-right-radius: 40px;
}

table tr:last-child td:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
}

table tr:last-child td:last-child {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
}
```

The effect of this is that I each 'corner' of the entire table is rounded. I want the paginated table to also have rounded corners - however, I cannot seem to modify the pagination code to add a rounded style to the bottom two corners. I'm really stuck.

Any help is appreciated!  Let me know if you need more information.

Here is a fiddle to give an example: https://jsfiddle.net/hermana/8nou03tc/37/

When I set the number of rows to be 5, for example, I would like the last two rows displayed to show up rounded.

Comment: Any fiddle/snippet?

Comment: What do you mean by "the paginated table"? Can you provide a link to a working demo?

Comment: @Mukyuu thanks - I created a fiddle and updated above :)

Comment: @AndyHoffman thank you, I added a link to a fiddle above

Comment: Hey @ellen, I solved this [here](https://jsfiddle.net/thLvd17e/). I applied the border radius to the `table` directly and then set `overflow: hidden` on the table.

Comment: @AndyHoffman that was exactly what I needed - thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question was answered in the comments by @AndyHoffman. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thLvd17e/).

```
table {
  background-color: black;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;  
}
```