# Implementing Bootstrap 4 DataTables

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am attempting to implement a bootstrap 4 datatable, and cannot seem to get it to work. In My head I have the required CSS

```
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I then have the following required scripts below:

```
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
```

I then call the scripts onto my standard formatted HTML table, with the correct ID as follows:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#myTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>
```

None of this However works, and the table displays using normal Bootstrap 4 Table, with no search/sorting function. Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

**EDIT: I tried this unfortunately it seemed to break the CSS for the whole site. All I really want to do is only show the first 10 rows of my bootstrap 4 table, but every time I google it it comes up with results for data tables. Is there any way to show just the first 10 rows of a standard bootstrap 4 table?**

Comment: Have you checked your console for error messages?

Comment: Yep, nothing to be seen...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like you haven't imported Jquery in your HTML File.
you need to use 3 files for Data Tables as follow

```
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js
```

But you only added

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js
```

Import JQuery before

> jquery.dataTables.min.js   and
>   dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js

after the imports of js and jquery files 
write your Jquery Code

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#myTable').DataTable();
    });
</script>
```

and for header

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css
```

check that as follow, This will work fine.

Comment: I tried this unfortunately it seemed to break the CSS for the whole site. All I really want to do is only show the first 10 rows of my bootstrap 4 table, but every time I google it it comes up with results for data tables. Is there any way to show just the first 10 rows of a standard bootstrap 4 table?

Comment: if it breaks CSS of the whole site it means you are using any files twice or used jquery twice .. it should not break the CSS, double-check it if you have imported CSS properly. if its possible upload your code on jsfiddle so i can check and let you know the exact problem.

Comment: Working Example of DataTables. Try it https://jsfiddle.net/ebRXw/2985/

Comment: I will try again- if I have multiple versions of JQuery, should I use the most up to date version?

Comment: yes use latest it will not make any issue.. and do check that fiddle I shared with you.. its working example. so you just need to copy and change as per your requirements.

Comment: I will try what you posted. Would it be possible to only show 10 rows using a standard bootstrap table, rather than a datatable?

Comment: yes it is possible, you have to code JS manually and there are some ways to do it through CSS also.. it only shows X no of rows as pr code..  for other rows you have to scroll for it ....

Comment: This would be the ideal situation for me- I have no need to sort data in ascending/descending. How would I go about this?

Comment: Manually done .. you can check  this and modify it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39087619/show-n-rows-per-page-in-html-table

Comment: Might be easier to just try get datatables working...looks compliacted. Thank you though, I'll try get datatables working.

Comment: I appear to have it working now, now I just need to figure out how to move the search bar, if possible, so that it is more prominent. I think my issue may now be lying in the fact that I am importing the html table into the document using the load() function.

Comment: It's alright, I managed to figure it out. I just can't get the responsive side of things to work- even at 100% width there's still a scroll bar.